# Arrays of hashes to hash

Tags: ruby

Task: convert this array of hashes:

```
animals = [
  {"cats" => 3},
  {"dogs" => 5 }
]
```

to this hash:

```
{
  "cats" => 3,
  "dogs" => 5
}
```

This is my solution, any feedback is appreciated :-)

```
animals.reduce({}) {|m,e|
  e.each{|k,v| m[k] = v}; m
}
```

Comment: You've given an example, but can you be more specific about the requirements and constraints? For example, is guaranteed that each element of `animals` is a Hash with a single entry? Is it guaranteed that there are no duplicates or clashes?

Comment: no constraints, it just has to work with that example :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The snippet `e.each{|k,v| m[k] = v}` does the same thing as the standard library method [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21), so the shortest way to write your solution is probably:

```
animals.reduce({}, :merge!)
```

Note that with this solution, if two hashes in the source array have duplicate keys, those coming later in the array will take priority and overwrite the duplicate keys from earlier in the array:

```
[{"egrets" => 17}, {"egrets" => 21}].reduce({}, :merge!)  # => {"egrets"=>21}
```

Also be aware that `merge!` is destructive to the original hash, which is fine here since we don't reuse the literal input to `reduce`. There is a non-destructive version, `merge`, which is better when the input needs to be preserved.